# Модуль RPI.GPIO

Tags: python, модули

Понадобился модуль RPi.GPIO. Вообщем скачал я его и распаковал и при установке через python setup.py install выдавало ошибку Unable to find vcvarsall.bat, немного поискать я смог устранить эту проблему , но за ней же сразу же другая...Ниже скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это модуль для raspberry pi, он не будет работать под windows.

Comment: Просто установить через pip на raspberry?

Comment: Да, нужно установить на raspberry.